# Using WPQ2FormCtx to read list item information [FAIL]

Tags: sharepoint-online

One day, I had just read one topic [SharePoint 2013: Using WPQ2FormCtx to read list item information]- which holds plenty of useful information and I applied one in my code and it works perfectly.

And boom right now, my page went dead. I don't know why and I start tracing and debugging my code on my custom webpart. The "WPQ2FormCtx" object doesn't exist in my source anymore, it changed to WPQ3FormCtx.

Any one have an idea about this? I wonder if Microsoft updated some stuff.

Can anyone give me a clue, a way to get the name of this object? Or the way you used to read list item information?

Have a nice day
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out about this a month ago and these values are subject to change.

What you can do instead is to loop over a certain number of WPQ you might want and return the first one or one that has the correct identifiable context.

To get around this problem you can do:

```
function getdata() {
  var ctx = {};

  for (var iCtx = 0; iCtx < 12/*whatever number u think is needed */; iCtx++) {
    if (typeof window['WPQ' + iCtx + 'FormCtx'] !== 'undefined') {
      ctx = window['WPQ' + iCtx + 'FormCtx'].ListData;
      ctx.Id = window['WPQ' + iCtx + 'FormCtx'].ItemAttributes.Id;
      break;
    }
  }

  return ctx;
}
```